# Convert a string to an associative array

Tags: php, string, parsing

How would you convert a string like that to an associative array in PHP?

```
key1="value" key2="2nd value" key3="3rd value"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to get the key/value pairs:

```
preg_match_all('/(\w+)="([^"]*)"/', $str, $matches);
```

But this would just get the complete key/value pairs. Invalid input like `key=value"` would not get recognized. A parser would do better.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: Gumbo's answer is a better solution to this.

This any good to you?

Assume your string is in a variable like this:

```
$string = 'key1="value" key2="2nd value" key3="3rd value"';
```

First:

```
$array = explode('" ', $string);
```

you now have

```
array(0 => 'key1="value', 1=>'key2="2nd value', 2=>'key3="3rd value');
```

Then:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($array as $chunk) {
  $chunk = explode('="', $chunk);
  $result[$chunk[0]] = $chunk[1];
}
```

Comment: having written this, I prefer gumbo's answer!

Comment: What about `key=" value"` or `key="="`?

Comment: totally - as I said, prefer yours!

Answer (score 1):

Using the regular expression suggested by Gumbo I came up with the following for converting the given string to an associative array:

```
$s = 'key1="value" key2="2nd value" key3="3rd value"';
$n = preg_match_all('/(\w+)="([^"]*)"/', $s, $matches);

for($i=0; $i<$n; $i++)
{
    $params[$matches[1][$i]] = $matches[2][$i];
}
```

I was wondering if you had any comments.